# AS3 Calculate if object is on other object and change Dynamic text

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I have this function. What it is supposed to do is calculate whether the Raisin cookie is on the plate (I have already declared all vars correctly) and have a dynamic text display the calorie count. When the cookie is out of the plate, then the calorie count should deduct the calorie count of the cookie (it should not reset as I have other cookies as well). The raisinOnce is a boolean that safeguards that the calories are not deducted before the cookie is added to the plate at least once.

```
function caloriesf(e:Event)
{
    calories.text="only "+String(caloriesv)+" calories!";
    if (((raisin.x > plateminx && raisin.x < platemaxx)&& (raisin.y > plateminy && raisin.y < platemaxx))&& raisinInPlate==false)
    {
        raisinOnce=true;
        caloriesv+=50;
        raisinInPlate=true;
        return;
    }
    else if (((raisin.x < plateminx && raisin.x > platemaxx)&&(raisin.y < plateminy && raisin.y > platemaxx)) && raisinOnce==true)
    {
        raisinInPlate=false;
        caloriesv-=50;
    }
}
```

Now this works correctly when the cookie is added to the plate, but not when it is removed! What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that the else didn't need statements and also I didn't need to use the Once boolean...the corrected code as follows (works)

```
function caloriesf(e:Event)
{
    calories.text="only "+String(caloriesv)+" calories!";
    if ((raisin.x > plateminx && raisin.x < platemaxx)&& (raisin.y > plateminy && raisin.y < platemaxy))
    {
        if (raisinInPlate==false)
        {
            caloriesv+=50;
            raisinInPlate=true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (raisinInPlate==true)
        {
            raisinInPlate=false;
            caloriesv-=50;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unless your plates are squares it will work - but for places and cookies you should actualy compare circles e.g. if distance from centers of circles is greater than sum of theirs radius than there is no collision at all if smaller than there is collision.